# Align text in custom ListView in table-like format

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, textview, position

I am building an app that I would like to support multiple device size.
In my app, I am using a listview to display data as well as a custom adapter. The background of the listview is an image I have done. This image is basically a  114heightX700width. with a small vertical divider at about 1/4 of the image.

In the left side, I need to center numbers with maximum 3 digit and on the left, a title.

It works great on Nexus 4, but if I try other devices with different dpi, it wont center anymore. Is there a way to "clip" the text positioning in the given image so that it is always at the same position no matter the device?

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/empty"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.00" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.89"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options:

1. Use a `LinearLayout` set all children to `match_parent` and set the `layout_weight` to 1 for every child. This will bring all children to the exact same size.
2. Use a 9patch background for each child. This will draw your background "around" the text.
3. Use a view in between the `TextView` to show the divider.

Anyway: RelativeLayouts/LinearLayout/FrameLayout with only one child do not make sense.
You should reduce the complexity of your layout.